# Sending text from client-side to a server-side program for processing

Tags: python, web

My goal is to send a line of text that is inputted by the user to a program running server side for processing. How can I have the HTML page upload the text to a specific directory on the server or directly to a python program running on the server?

Answer (score 0):

When the user submits their form, or triggers some other event, you can run an AJAX request to a PHP script on your server which will write the text to a file. Assuming jQuery has been included for simplicity's sake, you can do something like this in your html file:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your/file/location/here/writeToFile.php",
      data: {"text": $("#formField").text()},
      success: function() {
        alert("Your data has been submitted");
      }
    });
});
```

Then the PHP file on the server would look like this:

```
<?php
    $textToWrite = $_POST['text'];
    fwrite("your/file/directory/here/data.txt", $textToWrite);
?>
```

This would result in a text file at the location `your/file/directory/here` named `data.txt`.

From there, you should be able to have your python script read the file. You can also have the PHP script execute the python script if necessary.